# Serializacion y envio de objetos mediante Socket JAVA

Tags: java, socket

Saludos estoy realizando un proyecto en el cual dispongo de un ServerSocket donde trato de enviar a un Socket un objeto serializado con números aleatorios y la fecha en la que se generaron para que el cliente opere con ellos. Dispongo de un main(), un HiloServidor (que acepta un maximo de 10 conexiones) y una clase objeto de nombre Parametros. Y por el lado del cliente, una clase con el cliente y su objeto con los Parametros. El problema es que me salta este fallo. ¿Alguien podria ayudarme ?

-Proyecto Servidor-

Main

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package servidorsatelite;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Random;

/**
 *
 * @author DAM205
 */
public class ServidorSatelite extends Thread {

    static ServerSocket servidor;
    static final int puerto = 6000;
    static int conexionesActuales = 0;
    static Socket tabla[] = new Socket[10];

    static Parametros parametrosEstacion = new Parametros();
    static Parametros parametrosRover = new Parametros();

    Random coordenadaNEstacion = new Random();
    Random coordenadaEEstacion = new Random();
    Random coordenadaNRover = new Random();
    Random coordenadaERover = new Random();

    int numeroNEstacion, numeroEEstacion;
    int numeroNRover, numeroERover;

    Calendar instante;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        servidor = new ServerSocket(puerto);
        System.out.println("- Servidor satélite operativo -");
        System.out.println("-------------------------------\n");

        ServidorSatelite generadorCoordenadas = new ServidorSatelite();
        Thread hiloCoordenadas = new Thread(generadorCoordenadas);
        hiloCoordenadas.start();

        while (conexionesActuales <= 10) {
            Socket s = new Socket();
            try {
                s = servidor.accept();
            } catch (SocketException ns) {
                break;
            }
            tabla[conexionesActuales] = s;
            conexionesActuales++;
            HiloServidor hiloServidor = new HiloServidor(s, parametrosEstacion, parametrosRover);
            hiloServidor.start();
        }

        if(!servidor.isClosed())
            try{
                servidor.close();
            }catch (IOException ioe){
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }

        System.out.println("Servidor satelite deshabilitado");
        System.out.println("-------------------------------\n");

    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            instante = Calendar.getInstance();
            Date momenActual = instante.getTime();
            parametrosEstacion.setInstante(momenActual);
            parametrosRover.setInstante(momenActual);
            System.out.println(parametrosEstacion.getInstante());

            numeroNEstacion = coordenadaNEstacion.nextInt(50);
            parametrosEstacion.setNumeroN(numeroNEstacion);
            System.out.println("Estación punto N: " + parametrosEstacion.getNumeroN());

            numeroEEstacion = coordenadaEEstacion.nextInt(50);
            parametrosEstacion.setNumeroE(numeroEEstacion);
            System.out.println("Estación punto E: " + parametrosEstacion.getNumeroE());

            numeroNRover = coordenadaERover.nextInt(50);
            parametrosRover.setNumeroN(numeroNRover);
            System.out.println("Rover punto N: " + parametrosRover.getNumeroN());

            numeroERover = coordenadaERover.nextInt(50);
            parametrosRover.setNumeroE(numeroERover);
            System.out.println("Rover punto E: " + parametrosRover.getNumeroE());
            System.out.println("");

            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }

}
```

HiloServidor

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package servidorsatelite;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

/**
 *
 * @author DAM205
 */
public class HiloServidor extends Thread {

    Socket socket = null;
    Parametros paramEstacion = new Parametros();
    Parametros paramRover = new Parametros();

    ObjectOutputStream fsalida;

    public HiloServidor(Socket s, Parametros estacion, Parametros rover) {
        socket = s;
        paramEstacion = estacion;
        paramRover = rover;
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Comunico con: " + socket.toString());
                EnviarObjetos(paramEstacion);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private void EnviarObjetos(Parametros paramEstacion) throws IOException {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < ServidorSatelite.conexionesActuales; i++) {
            Socket s1 = ServidorSatelite.tabla[i];

            try {
                fsalida = new ObjectOutputStream(s1.getOutputStream());
                fsalida.writeObject(paramEstacion);
            } catch (SocketException se) {
                se.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Parametros

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package servidorsatelite;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")

/**
 *
 * @author DAM205
 */
public class Parametros implements Serializable {

    int numeroN, numeroE;
    Date instante;

    public Parametros() {
        super();
    }

    public Parametros(int numeroN, int numeroE, Date instante) {
        super();
        this.numeroN = numeroN;
        this.numeroE = numeroE;
        this.instante = instante;
    }

    public int getNumeroN() {
        return numeroN;
    }

    public void setNumeroN(int numeroN) {
        this.numeroN = numeroN;
    }

    public int getNumeroE() {
        return numeroE;
    }

    public void setNumeroE(int numeroE) {
        this.numeroE = numeroE;
    }

    public Date getInstante() {
        return instante;
    }

    public void setInstante(Date instante) {
        this.instante = instante;
    }
}
```

-Proyecto Cliente-

Main

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package servidorclientebase;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.net.Socket;

/**
 *
 * @author iberd
 */
public class ServidorClienteBase {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     * @throws java.io.IOException
     * @throws java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        String host = "localhost";
        int puerto = 6000;
        Parametros dato = new Parametros();

        System.out.println("Estación base operativa");
        System.out.println("-----------------------\n");
        Socket cliente = new Socket(host, puerto);

        //Flujo entrada para objetos
        ObjectInputStream perEnt = new ObjectInputStream(cliente.getInputStream());

        while (true){
        //Se recibe un objeto
            dato = (Parametros) perEnt.readObject();
        }
    }

}
```

Parametros

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package servidorclientebase;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")

/**
 *
 * @author DAM205
 */
public class Parametros implements Serializable {

    int numeroN, numeroE;
    Date instante;

    public Parametros() {
        super();
    }

    public Parametros(int numeroN, int numeroE, Date instante) {
        super();
        this.numeroN = numeroN;
        this.numeroE = numeroE;
        this.instante = instante;
    }

    public int getNumeroN() {
        return numeroN;
    }

    public void setNumeroN(int numeroN) {
        this.numeroN = numeroN;
    }

    public int getNumeroE() {
        return numeroE;
    }

    public void setNumeroE(int numeroE) {
        this.numeroE = numeroE;
    }

    public Date getInstante() {
        return instante;
    }

    public void setInstante(Date instante) {
        this.instante = instante;
    }

}
```

Cuando inicio el servidor y el cliente me dan los siguientes fallos:
Cliente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Servidor

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La clase *Parametros* esta definida en los dos paquetes. Aunque la definición sea idéntica, Java interpreta que son dos clases distintas. Por tanto estás serializando un objeto de la clase *servidorsatelite.Parametros* e intentando deserializarlo como si fuera de la clase *servidorclientebase.Parametros*. Indicando que utilizas la clase *Parametros* del paquete *servidorsatelite* se soluciona el problema:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    String host = "localhost";
    int puerto = 6000;
    servidorsatelite.Parametros dato = new servidorsatelite.Parametros();

    System.out.println("Estación base operativa");
    System.out.println("-----------------------\n");
    Socket cliente = new Socket(host, puerto);

    //Flujo entrada para objetos
    ObjectInputStream perEnt = new ObjectInputStream(cliente.getInputStream());

    while (true){
    //Se recibe un objeto
        dato = (servidorsatelite.Parametros) perEnt.readObject();
    }
```

Comment: Gracias solucione el problema finalmente. Gracias por todo ;D

Answer (score 0):

Un cast a una clase en Java luego de recibirlo en una deserialisación solamente funciona si:

- El nombre canónico de la clase es lo mismo (`com.miapp.paquete.Clase`)
- El numero de serie (implicando la versión de la clase) es lo mismo, o no hay
- La deserialisación es compatible con el objeto a que se hace el cast.

El nombre canónico es lo que sale en `objeto.getClass().getCanonicalName();`.

Para agregar a la respuesta correcta, quiero recomendar de en un caso de transferencia de objetos entre aplicaciones en sistemas distribuidas seguir los siguientes practicas:

- Definir todos los tipos compartidos en una biblioteca como modelo.
- implementar el numero de serie de las clases que se transmiten
- agregar la biblioteca como dependencia a ambos proyectos.

Para recibir los objetos, es recomendable de guardarlos en un objeto básico primero y luego comprobar el tipo con `instanceof`.

```
// asumiendo ObjectInputStream ois
Object o = ois.readObject();
if (o instanceof Parametros){
    ...
} else {
    // manejo de envío de objeto desconocido
}
```

Eso también evita que alguien puede atacar tu sistema con objetos aleatorios para causar excepciones. Hacer un cast inseguro a objetos recibidos sobre TCP puede causar vulnerabilidades de seguridad parecido a faltar de escapar datos del usuarios en consultas SQL, en el peor caso.

En tu caso, "solamente" se va caer la aplicación.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la aportación, soy nuevo en este mundo y aún me queda mucho de lo que aprender. Tratare de implementar la mejora en el código